# Connections of wires

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I have 6 volts batteries and I created a simple circuit of battery level indicator, the battery needs to supply another circuit and I need to connect the battery indicator level to the battery. And all the connected wires are connected to one supply. What will the battery level indicator read? The voltage from the supply or the voltage of the batteries? Dont have a picture of it. Please ask me if you need some clarifications.

Thank you for answering this question. [image]

Comment: We need to see a diagram of the circuitry of the regulator to be able to answer the question, although with the "booster" there the "voltage indicator" will likely *never* show the input voltage as indicated in the block diagram.

Answer (score 2):

> **The voltage from the supply or the voltage of the batteries?**

If they are connected, the voltage will be the same - this is what your indicator will indicate.

In some circumstances, one or other (or both) of the supply and the battery will catch fire in order to make this the case.

Comment: I posted the block diagram of the circuit. Can anyobe cheack it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically from what I perceive here is your booster feeds a regulator, not a battery. The battery is not fed voltage to charge and your looking to get the voltage of that auxiliary battery alone while it discharges to the regulator.

If that is correct the battery is already isolated.

If your charging the auxiliary battery, in order for you to test the voltage of the battery without testing the charger at the same time, you need to have a disconnect happen during testing. Otherwise your going to only be reading the voltage of the charger and the battery (may be the same, most likely not). This can happen with transistors fairly easy or you could automate the process with op-amps or microcontrollers. 
Key point being you cant test the battery under charge without getting the charger voltage mixed into it.

If your battery is additional voltage, as previously mentioned we would need to see the regulator schematic to determine if the regulator is feeding anything back into the battery or simply place a diode inline so as to not get voltage from that as feedback during testing. (should be done anyways, if not already in the regulator itself)

This looks like a UPS in my opinion and the auxiliary battery would need to be isolated from the input source if you were to charge and test simultaneously.